# Propagate bold (italic) font to inline math

Tags: bold, boldmath, bm

I use the package [`bm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bm) for proper italicised bold font in math-mode. Suppose we make some part of a sentence with math bold (via `\textbf{...}`). Is it possible to make all math for this part automatically bold?

E.g.

**input:** `\textbf{field~\(F\)}`

**desired:** `\textbf{\field~\(\bm{F}\)}`

---

Is it safe to define

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*{\textbf}[1]{%
    {\bfseries\boldmath #1}%
}
```

or would I miss some essential features of `bm`?

Comment: bm is the wrong tool here `\boldmath` is what you need, I would define a new command though, not redefine `\textbf` especially  not removing control over italic correction. Note most math publications do not make math bold in bold regions only using bold math fonts for semantic mathematical distinctions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend *not* using boldface for emphasis.

If you really want to, do it properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries\boldmath,\itshape}

\begin{document}

Take a \emph{field~\(F\)} and do something with~\(F\).

Outer \emph{first level \emph{second level} first level} outer.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However a bold italic F does not necessarily mean the same thing as a medium italic F and your readers might be puzzled about the different symbols.

Once you realize that boldface for emphasis is a punch in the eye of the reader, just remove the `\DeclareEmphSequence` line.

[image]

Comment: This looks really good! And on that note: I never wanted to emphasize with bold font, but only to use it for new definitions in my notes. It should punch me in the eye as I'm reading it (especially if I scroll through the pdf) ;)